# javascript to discover .flv url from any embedded flash video?

Tags: javascript, flash, video

Is there any javascript library out there that can find the url to the flash video file (.flv) on current page where it has an embedded flash video player? Ex. opens collegehumor.com video link, shows flash video url.

I have been looking through codes from chrome extensions which discovers flash video links for download but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser extensions can look into Flash internals and monitor your HTTP activity to see where data is being pulled from, however Javascript running in the document does not have permission to read either of those.

Some Flash apps expose some of their internals to Javascript, but they need to specifically write in that functionality, and for third parties this would be documented, presumably as an API. As far as I can tell, collegehumor doesn't provide any of that.

Comment: I see so basically sniff the HTTP for .flv being sent out?

Comment: Yes – but as far as I know it isn't possible for scripts running in a web page to monitor HTTP traffic on that page: extensions only manage this with higher permissions that come from integration with the browser application layer.